# Issue with masked textbox for website address using kendo ui

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, maskedtextbox

I am using kendo ui to for the masked textbox. I am done with phone number and fax number. but i want to put "http://_________________" for website textbox which should be variable length string. How can i achieve that?
I used following way to achieve phone number.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox()
                      .Name("phone_number")
                      .Mask("(999) 000-0000")
                      .Value("555 123 4567")
                )
```

Comment: I need help... anyone there?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, the MaskedTextBox widget works only with strict mask length. In other words, the widget's mask defines the length of the input, which cannot be dynamic.

I am afraid that this is a limitation with the widget and there is no feasible workaround for it.

You can vote for this functionality here:

- [Kendo UserVoice discussion](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/5924855-add-support-for-group-mask-sections-in-the-maskedt)

Comment: Yes you are right. I just tired of searching it. At last I used Jquery to show http://www.... on clicking that textbox :(... And yeah I will definitely vote for that. Thanks